# Angular: ngFor on child component and detect input changes

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a parent component, iterating over a list of objects. For each object in the list, I am creating a new child component with the object as input, like this :

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let object of objects">
        <child-component [childObject]="object"></child-component>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In parent component, I modify the objects list, changing some object properties. I want to be able to detect those changes in the corresponding child component and update the childObject when the parent modify a property from an object. Is that possible ?

(I already tried ngOnChanges but it's not working since the object references remain the same)

Comment: have you tried ChangeDetectorRef and its method .detectChanges() and TrackBy function for your *ngFor

Comment: no I didn't, how I can do that ?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef